# Native host connector is not detected. Refer to documentation for instructions about installing connector."

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell-extensions

Actually, I'm trying to add some extension to my Ubuntu GNOME, but it is showing some error when I'm trying.

The issue is like:

> "Although the GNOME Shell integration extension is running, the native host connector is not detected. Refer to documentation for instructions about installing the connector."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using Google Chrome, which needs a [special extension](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) to use the website. In Ubuntu the package is called `chrome-gnome-shell`.

If you're using Mozilla Firefox you can get an extension from the [Firefox Addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) site, although I've [read on OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/install-gnome-shell-extensions-firefox-chrome) that the Chrome extension works for Firefox as well.